# identical 3D physics simulations across different mobile devices

Tags: libgdx, game-physics, physics-engine

I created mobile a 3D game using Apple's SceneKit framework. The game heavily depends on physics simulations. Because of that, the physics simulations must be identical across devices. The SceneKit fails to do that as I am experiencing completely different physics simulations across different devices. Because of that, I am looking for a new frameworks or engines to use. Before I dive deeply into libGDX.. How does libGXD handle physics? Will my 3d simulations look identical across devices? If not, what tools do you recommend to use to create identical 3D physics?

Comment: Getting physics simulations to perform identically is surprisingly hard.  The problem often lies in the exact implementation of the floating point numbers on each device... they are not guaranteed to be the same even on the same manufacturer's various chip-sets.  The best solution I have found is to use entirely fixed-point arithmetic.

Comment: oh, are you implying that I should scale my physics world so that all the position and rotation data of bodies are integers? Don't know how to deal with frictions or similar because they are always a floating point number.

Comment: Not exactly, try the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic for an explanation of fixed point arithmetic.  In brief you decide that say the last 8 bits of your 32 bit integer are the fractional part, and for all of the arithmetic you use shifts to keep the fractional part the same size.

Answer (score 0):

First off, due to floating point hardware differences, you will probably never achieve 100% identical physics simulations across different platforms.

Now, Libgdx doesn't have a built in physics engine, but instead has wrappers around the [Box2D](http://box2d.org/) and the [Bullet Physics](http://bulletphysics.org/) libraries. Since SceneKit was designed with casual games in mind and cross-platform, deterministic physics probably wasn't considered a top priority, you probably will have better results using the Bullet Physics library.

Comment: On a personal note I really like Libgdx, and can't recommend against using it.